# UINavigation Controller Swift5 .Переход на view

Tags: ios, swift, view, navigation

У меня есть Navigation контроллер и по UIButton я перехожу на простой ViewController.

Можно ли вернуться назад с  View controller'a при  помощи обычной кнопки на 
Navigation controller ,  а не по кнопке Back в Navigation Bar

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontrolleranimated?language=objc

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBAction func backToNavView( _sender: UIButton)
{    

 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)
}
```